# Not issue can be found with sonarlint 2.0 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarlint

I'm using Sonarlint 2.0 plugin in Eclipse. However, it couldn't detect the sonar issues for new created files. Is there anything I need configure to make it work?

Comment: Can you check if SonarLint is activated in project properties -> SonarLint?